# Prevent TinyMCE wrapping text in p tags on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

Sorry for my english, I'm not a native speaker.

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours with no luck so far. 
The question looks like a duplicate of questions asked previously here on Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions found here worked for me.

TinyMCE wraps anything you put in there inside p tags. I need to change the forced_root_block setting of tinymce to prevent this but I have no idea on how to achieve that on Wordpress.

I tried putting the code found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/tinymce-advanced-newline-problem) in my functions.php, but It did not work. Also, the problem doesn't revolve around "wpautop". It's just a TinyMCE problem: it puts the p tags as a default behaviour because it needs a root block. In my case I don't need a root block, because the editor's content is just a plain text whose root block is in my template's code. The added p tags simply break my layout, putting unnecessary html elements.

I tried using the TinyMCE advaced plugin, which has this option:

`Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the Text editor`

but when this is not checked has the effect of "stripping" all the p tags, even the ones I intentionally use in the editor.

All I want to achieve is to **prevent the editor from adding unwanted p tags** and, at the same time, **keep the p tags I intentionally use**.

Is there a way to edit the forced_root_block setting of TinyMCE on Wordpress?

Comment: You mean that when you press enter in the visual mode, it should add two `<br />` instead of a new paragraph?

Comment: No, if I typed "Lorem Ipsum" in the editor, it automatically wrapped it in p tags. And that's what I wanted to prevent. Found the solution, edited my post. Thank you

Comment: You better should post the solution as an answer and accept it (after 24h), so your question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: After too many hours I was messing up between two different Wordpress installations I was working on at the same time. The solution of the linked post worked for me, but I was checking the results on the other site. By putting this:

```
function change_mce_options($init){
    $init["forced_root_block"] = false;
    $init["force_br_newlines"] = true;
    $init["force_p_newlines"] = false;
    $init["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;
    return $init;       
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init','change_mce_options');
```

in my functions.php, TinyMCE stopped putting anything inside p tags. The `Stop removing the <p> and <br /> tags when saving and show them in the Text editor` of TinyMCE Advaced needs to be checked.

Comment: plus 1 for posting the found solution

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set

```
forced_root_blocks: false,
```

You can have a look at this [wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-tinymce-configuration/) to change this setting.
Here is another possibility: http://wpengineer.com/1963/customize-wordpress-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. The plugin you suggested does probably the same thing of the code I put in my functions.php: allow me to disable the root block.

Answer (score 0):

Add this filter to `functions.php`:

```
function my_mce_options( $init ) {
    $init['wpautop'] = false;
    $init['indent'] = true;
    $init['tadv_noautop'] = true;
    return $init;       
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_options' );
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?